# How can I count the amount of values in different columns in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, count, row, multiple-columns

For example, I have a table with these values:

| ID | Date | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/11/2021 | A |  | A | B |
| 2 | 01/11/2021 | B | B |  |  |

The A and B values are dynamic, they can be other characters as well.

Now I need somehow to get to the result that id 1 has 2 occurences of A and one of B. Id 2 has 0 occurences of A and 2 occurences of B.

I'm using dynamic SQL to do this:

```
for v_record in table_cursor
loop
    for i in 1 .. 4
    loop
        v_query := 'select col'||i||' from table where id = '||v_record.id;
        execute immediate v_query into v_char;
        if v_char = "any letter I'm checking" then
            amount := amount + 1;
        end if;
    end loop;
    -- do somehting with the amount
end loop;
```

But there has to be a better much more efficient way to do this.

I don't have that much knowledge of plsql and I really don't know how to formulate this question in google. I've looked into pivot, but I don't think that will help me out in this case.

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: You should also include what the expected output looks like.  This is not obvious from your cursor script.

Comment: Actually there is no expected output. I just have to put the data in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the number of *columns* would be fixed at four, you could use a union aggregation approach here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, Col1 AS val FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Col2 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Col3 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Col4 FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t2.val,
    COUNT(c.ID) AS cnt
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM yourTable) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT val FROM cte) t2
LEFT JOIN cte c
    ON c.ID = t1.ID AND
       c.val = t2.val
WHERE
    t2.val IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    t1.ID,
    t2.val;
```

This produces:

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: It's 31 columns, but I can go on from here. Thanks!